# Installing R package XML fails despite having all dependencies

Tags: r, xml, install.packages

Running on Linux LEAP,  R 4.1.2 (latest official release for this OS)
Trying to install (in Rstudio ) R package XML. It fails with this  (relevant lines):

```
Checking directory of LIBXML_INCDIR
Located parser file /usr/include/libxml2/parser.h
Checking for 1.8:  /usr/include/libxml2
Using libxml2.*
checking for gzopen in -lz... no
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml... no
configure: error: "libxml not found"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
```

But I HAVE zlib & libxml2 installed & up to date. Have specified correct paths for these libraries, and  some other flags, in ~/.Renviron :

```
LIBXML_INCDIR=/usr/include/libxml2
LIBXML_LIBDIR=/usr/lib64
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
PKG_LIBS=-L/lib64 -lz
PKG_LIBDIR=/lib64
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/include/libxml2
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2
```

And verified with Sys.getenv that they are set correctly in the R session, before running the install. I think the output lines:

```
Located parser file /usr/include/libxml2/parser.h
Checking for 1.8:  /usr/include/libxml2
Using libxml2.*
```

imply that it is looking in the right place and HAS found libxml2. Yet it then cant find xmlParseFile and exits with "libxml not found".

Things I tried (with a  little bit of help from chatgpt...)

1. Setting config vars in the R session and  in the install.packages command itself ( configure.args or configure.vars)
2. Installing from source
3. Installing from source in bash with  R CMD INSTALL (after exporting config vars in  bash shell)
4. installing from github using remotes package
   Everything gives the same error message. Not managing to get more info on the error -  bash install doesnt produce a config.log , and setting Sys.setenv(R_INSTALL_STAGED = "yes") gives no additional info .
   Am totally stumped! any ideas would be so much appreciated...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. On ubuntu here, but what does `sudo locate pkgconfig | grep xml` output?

Comment: Hi tnx! I also have libxml2 in some miniconda environments, so the above gives many results, but the system-wide location is '/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc
' , so I set the R variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH to that location in the .Renviron file, and it seems to be defined correctly: Sys.getenv("PKG_CONFIG_PATH")
[1] "/usr/lib64/pkgconfig"

Comment: As `/lib64` may be considered a nonstandard install (not checked), perhaps a sym link from  `/usr/lib64/libz`  to `/lib64/libz` solves as it is gzopen that is not being found, as as best I know, libxml-2.0.pc wouldn't contain that libz location info. And then test in the `~/XML$./configure` if it is then being picked up.

Comment: Consider, this is very old very working code dev't in 1999, now maintained by default by cran, but 'look for' innovation in the ./configure is looking for a *-config file and that has subsequently been replaced by the .pc innovation, but the .pc doesn't inform a configure make process that isn't designed to work with it.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I think /usr/lib64 is standard in my system at least, cause I have lots of libraries there (libz as well as libxml2), and dont want to start messing up with symbolic links...especially as if I understand it right, setting all these environmental variables should point it to the right location in any case . BTW another weird thing - you're right lz implies libz, but in teh error mesaage it refers only to libxml.

Comment: Update:  tried installing a different package that needs libxml2 ("rvest"), just to verify my install is OK. This succeeded with a version warning (program compiled against libxml 210 using older 209, I dont think thats whats crashing the XML install)